# Unresolved function or method render() for React Hello-World app in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I used `create-react-app` to create a hello-world React application, then I used IntelliJ IDEA to open the application. But there is a warning for the index.js as following. I was wondering how to get rid of this warning.

[image]

This is a hello-world application created by `create-react-app` and I guess it needs to install some library in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Would be good to show some code (other than just this screenshot).

Comment: I attached the code. This is a hello-world application using create-react-app and I guess it needs to install some library in IntelliJ IDEA:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In working directory:

```
npm install @types/react-dom --save
```

And in settings, check local node_modules folder, only those two should be checked.

[image: settings window]

Now, everything will work as expected:

[image: Works now]